# D3 v4 breaking on interpolate function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to understand why D3 v4 is no longer compatible with my script. I think this is because some functions have been deprecated and are no longer in use.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/m65fg/2/) no longer works with D3 v4. I think this is due to the following line:

```
var d3LineBasis = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis");
```

I have tried using d3.curveBasis as found on this [link](http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/c25a147970def2b02d8c7c2719dc7502), but it has not resolved the issue and the script is not running.

Comment: Here is the v4 version: http://jsfiddle.net/ngs3466k/

Comment: None of your fiddle worked when I tried, setting the url to https instead of http drew something. So maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Hello Gerardo - you are spot on once again. If you would like to post this as an answer I shall of course accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065737/error-with-interpolate)

Answer (score 1):

Try [curves](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves):

```
var line = d3
    .line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.price); })
    .curve(d3.curveNatural);
```